# Replacing an element of a matrix by a function of that same element

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to replace an element of a matrix by a function of its current value. The code I'm using is as follows

```
T = {{2, 3}, {3, 2}, {1, 4}}
KNeeds = Transpose[T][[2]]
pos = Flatten[{Position[KNeeds, Min[KNeeds]], 2}]
ReplacePart[T, pos -> T[[pos[[1]]]] - Epsilon]]
```

I was hoping to obtain `{{2, 3}, {3, 2-Epsilon}, {1, 4}},` but I get `{{2, 3}, {3, {3 - Epsilon, 2 - Epsilon}}, {1, 4}}.`

I've also tried `ReplacePart[T, pos -> T[[pos]] - Epsilon]],` but then I get `{{2, 3}, {3, {{3 - Epsilon, 2 - Epsilon}, {3 - Epsilon, 
    2 - Epsilon}}}, {1, 4}}.`

Comment: `MapAt[# - \[Epsilon] &, T, pos]` ?

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks @b.gatessucks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this please:

```
pos = Cases[Position[T, Min[T[[All, 2]]]], {_, 2}]

ReplacePart[T, Thread[pos -> Extract[T, pos] - Epsilon]]

MapAt[# - Epsilon &, T, pos]
```

Comment: (Hopefully my *gedanken Mathematica* got this okay.)

Comment: Wouldn't your code replace all ´2´ in the matrix by ´2-Epsilon´? This is not what I intended @J.M. is computer-less

Comment: It shouldn't; that is what `Cases[]` is for. Did you look at the output of `pos`?

Comment: You're right, of course. Just to make sure I understand your code, in case the minimum value appeared on several rows of column 2 , it would replace all of them, woudn't it? @J.M. is computer-less

Comment: Right, `m = Min[T[[All, 2]]]` will yield the minimum value in the second column of `T`, and then `Position[T, m]` will give (possibly multiple) locations of the minimum in the whole of `T`. You can then use `Cases[]` to filter out what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much. @J.M. Is computer-less

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
T /. {a_, 2} -> {a, 2 - epsilon}

(*  {{2, 3}, {3, 2 - epsilon}, {1, 4}}  *)
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

```
ReplacePart[T, pos -> T[[## & @@ pos]] - ϵ]
```

> {{2, 3}, {3, 2 - ϵ}, {1, 4}}

Also

```
T = {{2, 3}, {3, 2}, {1, 4}};
T[[## & @@ pos]] = T[[## & @@ pos]] - ϵ;
T
```

> {{2, 3}, {3, 2 - ϵ}, {1, 4}}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{2, 3}, {3, 2}, {1, 4}};
```

Using `PositionSmallest` (new in 13.2) and `ReplaceAt` (new in 13.1)

```
p = Append[-1] @ PositionSmallest[Last /@ list]
```

{2, -1}

```
ReplaceAt[a_ :> a - ϵ, p] @ list
```

{{2, 3}, {3, 2 - ϵ}, {1, 4}}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{2, 3}, {3, 2}, {1, 4}};
```

Using `SequencePosition` and `SubsetMap`:

```
p = SequencePosition[#, {{_, Min@#[[All, 2]]}}] &@list;

SubsetMap[# - ϵ &, list, p]

(*{{2, 3}, {3, 2 - ϵ}, {1, 4}}*)
```